General linear map from a bivector to a vector in 3D
I'm trying to apply Geometric Algebra to  a physics problem I'm looking at, which in its classical form involves a linear map from an area element to a vector. The natural formulation of this in Geometric Algebra is clearly a linear map $S$ from a bivector $A$ to a vector $v$. My best guess is something like
$$v = S \wedge A$$
where
$$S = S^{ij} (-I) e_i e_j $$
using Einstein summation convention, and where $I = e_1e_2e_3$ is the pseudoscalar and the $e_i$ are basis vectors.
My goal is for the $i^\text{th}$ component of $v$ corresponding to the plane of $A$ perpendicular to $j$ to be given by $S^{ij}$. Have I set this up correctly?
I tested it out by setting e.g. $A = |A|e_2e_3$ and checking that I indeed pulled out $v^i = S^{i1} |A|$.

I hope the question is clear, I'm not sure how exactly to explain what it is I want.

Subsidiary question: is there a way to set this up so that the components $S^{ij}$ retain the same interpretation, but $S$ is defined so as to have $v = SA$?

Edit: following a request for more context, I can add that my object $S$ is meant to represent the stress tensor from continuum mechanics. In particular, this is defined with reference to a traction vector $v$ and a reference plane $A$, such that $S^{ij}$ is the $i^\text{th}$ component of the traction applied on the $j^\text{th}$ plane (where e.g. the plane $j=3$ is the 1–2 plane).

(1) Your $v$ is a trivector. (2) You cannot represent arbitrary linear maps from bivectors to vectors using only geometric algebra operations. You should add more context about what exactly the map $S$ is supposed to be.

I've added more context, is that useful? Also, could you explain why $v$ is a trivector? Taking the example mentioned I have $$v= |A|S^{ij} (-I) e_i e_j \wedge e_2 e_3$$ $$= |A| S^{i1} (-I) e_i I$$ $$= |A| S^{i1} e_i$$ i.e. a vector. Is that not correct?

I'm not sure what you think you're doing. First, if $S$ is to be a vector, you cannot write $S=S^{ij}(-I)e_ie_j$ without restrictions on $S$ since $e_ie_j$ is only a bivector when $i\ne j$; when $i=j$ it is a scalar. Overall it's better to just write $S=S^{ij}(-I)(e_i\wedge e_j)$. Now, since $S$ is a vector and $A$ is a bivector, $S\wedge A$ is a trivector; wedge products always add grades together. You seem to believe that $a(b\wedge c) = (ac)\wedge c$, which is very, very false. You also seem to think that $e_j\wedge(e_2e_3) = I$, which is false unless $e_j=e_1$; otherwise you get zero.

See Geometric Algebra for Physicists by Doran and Lasenby. This is a good introduction to the subject, and section 6.6.2 has a little bit about stress tensors, which they just represent as a linear function from a normal vector to a force. You could certainly replace the normal vector with a bivector, but the way they use it a normal vector seems more ergonomic.

Evidently I don't know what I'm doing. I'm not sure why it looks like I want $S$ to be a vector; in the traditional formulation, $S$ is a 3×3 tensor, and a vector just doesn't have enough components to represent it. Reading your reply it looks like 1) I don't understand how the algebra (e.g. associativity) works, and 2) I can't represent nine independent components in this way.

The bit where $e_j \wedge e_2 e_3 = \delta_{1j} I$ is apparently the only bit of the calculation I got right. (I assume when you write $a(b\wedge c) \neq (ac) \wedge c$ you mean $a(b\wedge c) \neq (ab) \wedge c$?) Thank you very much for the detailed reference: I'll try to get my hands on the book and specifically §6.6.2.

Yes, the extra $c$ was a typo.
